# For which values ​​of $a$ and $b$ does the equation $\sin(\sqrt{x})=\frac{a}{x}+b$ have no solution?

Tags: calculus

I‘m trying to find for what values of $a$ and $b$ there is no solutions to this equation:

$$\sin(\sqrt{x})=\frac{a}{x}+b$$

I would like to get some advice.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell what you have tried up to now?

Comment: for starters, it must be $$\left|\;\frac ax+b\;\right|\le 1\ldots$$

Comment: I`m still don`t understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k=\sqrt{x}$. Reformat the equation as $sin(k)-b=\frac{a}{k^2}$, with the condition that $k>0$.

We consider three cases: $a>0$, $a<0$, and $a=0$.

First, assume $a>0$. Then, The graph of $y=\frac{a}{k^2}$ in respect to $k$ has a vertical asymptote at $k=0$, a horizontal asymptote at $y=0$, and is located in the first quadrant. A visual example can be seen here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fx%5E2+for+x+from+0+to+4.

We see that any $sin(k)$ graph translated in the positive y-direction inevitably intersects with $y=\frac{a}{k^2}$. In order for $y=sin(k)-b$  to not intersect this graph, the maximum value of the sine curve must lie on the horizontal asymptote $y=0$ or below. Thus, we see that the two graphs do not intersect for $a>0$ and $b\geq1$.

Similarly, for the parallel case of $a<0$ (in which the graph is reflected across the x-axis), we see that the two graphs do not intersect for $a<0$ and $b\leq1$.

For the case of $a=0$, we require that $sin(k)\neq b$. This is satisfied when $b>1$ or $b<1$.

Comment: You can use `\sin` to get $\sin$ in place of $sin$. For further advice and reference on writing mathematics on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020).